# How to configure Goals in ExactTarget Journey Builder Interaction

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm trying to find documentation on creating Goals in a Journey Builder Interaction. I've read [the documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-AU/documentation/journey_builder/) and this is not explained anywhere.

From the Journey Builder Interaction Canvas Interface, it appears that Goals are configured in a similar way to Triggers, but I can't figure out how to set conditions for a Goal. For example, I want to set a goal as "I want 80% of customers to install the mobile app".

I've already defined an Attribute Group in Contact Builder and can drag a condition to select a 'HasAppInstalled' column to build an expression for a Goal, but I can't figure out how to set this to "80% of customers" from my Data Extension. I'm very surprised to see that while Goals is a prominent feature in Journey Builder, it does not appear to have any documentation. I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A goal is created the same way a new "Trigger" is setup.  The trigger/goal evaluates each individual Contact in your Interaction.  Once a Contact meets that criteria set forth in the Trigger, it is added to the total of those meeting your Goal.

You would create a "Trigger" (to use as your goal) that states "HasAppInstalled" equal to YES.  Then on the conversion target screen of your Goal Setup, you would define your percentage of the population, similar to the attached.  This then monitors your Interaction and each new Contact that meets this criteria will be adding towards the total percentage of that population.

Hope that helps!

[image]